# C++ Map Output Formatting Garbage

Tags: c++, dictionary, format

I have a `std::map<char*,std::map<char*, char*>> ini;` which I read an ini file into.

Ini files have format of:

```
[SECTIONAME]
key=value
[SECTIONNAME2]
key2=value2
```

So it is basically  `map<sectionName, map<key, value>>`.

I insert values into the map fine, it seems:

```
std::cout << "inserting at section: '" << currentSection.c_str() << "', tag: '" << tag.c_str() << "', value: '" << value.c_str() << "'" << std::endl;  
ini.find(const_cast<char *>(currentSection.c_str()))->second.insert(std::make_pair(const_cast<char *>(tag.c_str()), const_cast<char *>(value.c_str())));
std::cout << "inserted key: '" << ini.find(const_cast<char *>(currentSection.c_str()))->second.find(const_cast<char *>(tag.c_str()))->first << "'" << std::endl;
std::cout << "inserted value: '" << ini.find(const_cast<char *>(currentSection.c_str()))->second.find(const_cast<char *>(tag.c_str()))->second << "'" << std::endl;
```

It seems to go through all right:

```
inserting at section: 'SCENARIO', tag: 'id', value: '1'
inserted key: 'id'
inserted value: '1'
inserting at section: 'SCENARIO', tag: 'base', value: '1'
inserted key: 'base'
inserted value: '1'
```

I iterate and print out the values:

```
std::map<char*, std::map<char*, char*>>::iterator iter;
for(iter = ini.begin(); iter != ini.end(); iter++) 
{
    std::map<char*, char*> innermap = iter->second;
    std::map<char*, char*>::iterator iterinner; 
    std::cout << "found section: '" << iter->first << "'" << std::endl;
    for(iterinner = innermap.begin(); iterinner != innermap.end(); iterinner++) 
    {
        std::cout << "key: '" << iterinner->first << "', value: '" << iterinner->second << "'" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

After I iterate through it and print it out, I get this:

```
found section: 'á♦╧'
key: '', value: ''
key: 'Φ↑╧', value: ''
```

Why do I get garbage on the iteration? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The pointer returned by `std::string::c_str` is only valid until you "do something else" with the `std::string`. You are probably pointing to something entirely invalid.

Comment: I saw `std::map<char*,std::map<char*, char*>>` and knew I wouldn't like this question. Then I saw `const_cast<char *>(currentSection.c_str())` and decided.. I'm outta here.

Comment: What Neil Kirk is trying to say is that you might find it worthwhile to reconsider your design...

Comment: Your code is totally wrong, not just a bad design. c_str returns a const char * for a reason. You can't circumvent the protections of the language and expect it to work. Anyway, to be helpful, you should use `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>>`

Comment: Thanks everyone, `std::string` worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a pointer as a key, as it will be the actual *pointer* that is the key and not what it points to. If you want to use a string as a key then use `std::string`.

I of course recommend you to use `std::string` as the data in the inner map as well.

Storing pointers, especially pointers to temporary data as you seem to do, is a recipe for disaster and undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm new to C++. I didn't 100% know behaivor of c_str(). `std::string` worked on first try. I have to rework other parts to work with `std::string`. TY

Answer (score 0):

const_cast done on object originally declared as const is undefined.
Not sure if that is the case with the internal representation of data returned by c_str()

Also read here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

"The pointer returned may be invalidated by further calls to other member functions that modify the object."

As suggested by Jaochim use std::string as key